# Java: Using a HashMap as a sparse vector

Tags: java

I am using HashMap with integer keys,

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> feature_vector = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
```

and while reading data, add a new member when the value is not 0,

```
if (value != 0)
                feature_vector.add(index, value);
```

For anything that deals with this `feature_vector`, how can I just iterate over the "non-empty" positions of this `feature_vector`? I don't want to increment the key from 0 to the size of the `feature_vector` and check the value of every single key, which slows the program down.

Meaning there will be cases when the feature vector looks like:
1->7, 3->0, 4->5, 5->9, ...
(the second key has no value, so there would not be a second key and its value)

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: If you're already not adding indexes that have zero values to the map, then the only entries inside will be the nonzero ones.  You can use the `HashMap.entrySet()` method (which is iterable) to explore the contents (both keys and values together), or use `HashMap.keySet()` for just the keys (indices).

Comment: Damn, totally forgot about the entrySet() method... Thank you William!

Comment: Not sure if it's required but if you use a `TreeMap` instead of a 'HashMap', the keys / entries will be sorted by Integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
    Set<Integer> keys = feature_vector.keySet();

    for(Integer key : keys) {
        Double value = feature_vector.get(key);
        //do what ever you want with the key and value in here...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

More efficient than iterating over keys is to iterate directly over key-value pairs:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Double> entry : feature_vector.entrySet()) {
  Integer key = entry.getKey();
  Double value = entry.getValue();
  ...
}
```

This avoids looking up the value.